# WGet mirroring without putting it in a subdirectory (i.e. domain.com)

Tags: directory, wget, mirror

I am trying to mirror a website (with permission, of course), but the files download into foo.com.

```
wget -mkp http://foo.com
```

gives me a folder called foo.com with all the files.

how do i get it to download the files to the current directory?

EDIT: I still want file hierarchy, but i want the root of the hierarchy to be the current directory

Answer (score 8, accepted):

-n is what'll help you here.

`wget -nH --mirror http://example.com`

Answer (score 4):

try to use wget within "-nd" param

```
wget -nd --mirror http://example.com
```